# How do i visualize azure ml predictions in power bi

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I am working with azure ML notebook  for timeseries predictions
I have done everything  and i have my predictions  however i want to have my data and my predictions  visualized  in power bi.
How do i save my data back to azure blob so i can utilize  it in power bi?
Or anyotherway to visualize in power bi

Answer (score 1):

> How do i save my data back to azure blob so i can utilize it in power bi?

There are few cases where you can achieve this

### **WAY - 1**

You can store the whole prediction into a data frame and then save the data frame into blob storage while you are performing in a notebook. You can also refer a sample from [Configure a training run with data input and output - amlrelsa-ms](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/work-with-data/datasets-tutorial/scriptrun-with-data-input-output/how-to-use-scriptrun.ipynb).

### WAY - 2

You can use the Azure data factory to send the predictions of Azure ML to Azure blob storage by having a pipeline configured. You can check [Machine Learning Workflow with Azure Data Factory - Rahulraj Singh](https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-an-end-to-end-machine-learning-workflow-with-azure-data-factory-f16cbeeffd94) for the same.

> Or anyotherway to visualize in power bi

You can directly load the Azure ML data from Power Query Editor.

[image]

Make sure you login to your Account and from there you can select the one that you created from the Train and deploy a machine learning model.

[image]

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Tutorial: Consume Azure Machine Learning models in Power BI - MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-aml-integrate)
2. [Azure Machine Learning in Power BI Dataflows - Power BI blog](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Azure-Machine-Learning-in-Power-BI-Dataflows/ba-p/709744)